# Sort GraphQL query randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am looking for a solution to **randomly** `sort` a **[GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/)** query. I have looked through the documentation and it appears that their is no options.

Does anyone know of one or a workaround to randomising the following query?

```
query {
  allContentfulAttraction(
    limit: 4
    filter: { location: { eq: "AttractionLocation1" } }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL simply provides a framework for resolving and validating field values based on a schema. It does not come with any preset means of filtering or sorting the queried data. It's up to the server whether to expose ways for the client to do that, and how to implement that functionality.

With regards to Gatsby specifically, looking at their API supports querying random nodes. At best, you could query for all nodes, and then select a random set of elements from the returned data by using lodash's `sampleSize` or Chance's `pickset`.

Comment: The problem of this approach (in Gatsby) is that it will increase building times once the number of posts goes up. It indeed would be much more efficient to be able to ask only for a limited number of posts already randomized

Comment: Yes, it *would* be more efficient to be able to do this through the API. However, if the API does not support the functionality, then the only option is to do it client-side.

Comment: Let's hope for a future implementation. With gatsby, if you do the query in gatsby-node and pass only the reduced number of posts within the context, build times are kept under control

Comment: The query returning a random set in Gatsby would result in the page being rebuilt regardless as the props have changed and therefore so has the HTML that would be generated.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/ says sorting is handled by whichever framework you're using, such as [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/filtering) [`orderBy`](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/) or [Lighthouse](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.12/api-reference/directives.html#orderby) `@orderBy`.